# How might I determine the number of lines of code in a C++ project?

Tags: visual-studio, code-metrics, lines-of-code

Is there a quick way, in Visual Studio, to know how many lines of code exist in a project?

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2008, right click a project and select "Calculate Code Metrics". It includes a few other metrics like cyclomatic complexity. However, it only counts real lines of code, not empty lines or lines with }'s for example.

Comment: What version(s) of VS2008 is this in? I'm running Professional, and don't see it...

Comment: It is team edition only - on the developer menu. Not that we have it, because like most people we don't use team.

Answer (score 2):

Install cygwin, start a bash shell, cd to the top directory and issue something like:

find . -name "*.cpp" -exec cat {} \; | wc -l

Paul.

Comment: This ignores .c/.h files, forks a new process for every source file, doesn't give a final total, and counts meaningless lines (blank lines, comments, lines containing only braces, etc.)

Comment: I generally get the counts for the header files independently; don't care about CPU usage and believe that there are no such things as meaningless lines.

Comment: You can also do 'find . -name "*cpp" | xargs cat | wc -l', or in zsh (and possibly bash 4) 'wc -l **/*cpp | tail -n1'.

How do you do it in windows without visual studio?

Comment: Install a Unix shell like Cygwin. Or if you have a real sense of fun, install a VM emulator like VirtualBox, and a Linux distro like Debian, share the Windows filesystem into Samba and then hit the sources directly with bash.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the [line counter add-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsxfaq/archive/2008/03/28/how-to-create-a-line-counter-using-an-add-in.aspx) from the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html). Works well enough.

#### See also the answers on: [Simple script to count NLOC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323419/simple-script-to-count-nloc)

Answer (score 1):

For a more general solution which will give you line counts and many more useful metrics, I can strongly recommend [Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/) which is free and can be integrated with VS.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly use http://cloc.sourceforge.net/ to obtain code metrics on several languages including C++.